# Radio Button inside grid view control not firing oncheckedchanged event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have following code in my application I have a gridview control insde my grid view I have radio button defined as templetefield.

```
<asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function RadioCheck(rb) {
            var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdAllPartsRequestList.ClientID%>");
            var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
                    if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                        rbs[i].checked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    </script>

    <asp:TemplateField>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                oncheckedchanged="rbSelected_CheckedChanged" GroupName="RequestSelection" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</<asp:View>
```

Code Behind   .CS

```
protected void rbSelected_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Now my problem is upon running my page when I click the radio button the Event doesn't fire. `oncheckedchanged` is not firing.

Surprisingly The same functionality works fine in another page with in the grid view.

I have searched the web for this answers. But so far nothing worked out.   I have Update Panel in  my Master Page.. I have tried to play with `UpdateMode="Always"`  and `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` but so far nothing worked out please help!

Comment: You didn't close your view . </<asp:View> and can you post all your code together ?

Comment: Yes i did close the view my page is huge cant post complete here. The page works except it didn't invoke the event when i click radio inside the gridview.

Comment: You don't need to post all... You just post the GridView with 1 or 2 column.
Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
   void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {

        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

          Radiobutton rb = e.Row.FindControl("rbSelected") as Radiobutton;
          rb.oncheckedchanged += this.rbSelected_CheckedChanged;

        }

  }
```

The event will be added to the radiobutton on rowdatabound event of GridView...

Hope this helps you...